# List component scroller remains full height of View

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, list, scrollbar

I am working on a Flex mobile Application and I am using s:List defined in actionscript component with MXML renderer.

In my sView:

```
var movieList:List = new List();
private function created(event:FlexEvent):void
{
   movieList.itemRenderer = new ClassFactory(MovieRenderer);
   movieList.dataProvider = new ArrayList();
   movieList.useVirtualLayout = false;
   movieList.pageScrollingEnabled = true; // if this is omitted scroll bar is invisible
   this.addElement(movieList);
}
```

After HTTPService call is returned:

```
private function movieDataReady(event:events.ExternalDataEvent):void{
     movieList.dataProvider.addItem(event.result);
}
```

Each event.result item is a custom Object.

The issue is that the scroller seems to be the full height of the list as opposed to the view/screen. This renders it useless as you cannot scroll. If you try it does scroll but goes back as soon as you release. Scroller seems to be about the height of the combined height of all list items.

I had it working before but I made some changes and can't figure out what I am missing this time.

Comment: What you explain sounds like expected behavior.  Maybe you need to add a scroll bar to the view? Or re-size the list so it doesn't get sized beyond the viewable area.  Have you tried setting the percentWidth and percentHeight of the list to 100?  Also, I strongly recommend reading up on the Flex Component LifeCycle; it is unusual to create children outside of the createChildren() method.

Comment: percentWidth/Height doesn't fix the issue. By unusual do you mean adding the items one by one? If so same issue happens even if I set dataProvider to ArrayList("all items inside"); Reason I prefer to each item is because it is faster(items appear as soon as they are loaded. As for adding a scroller to the View, wouldn't I end up with 2 scollbars then, one for list and one for view? Seems like list should be able to handle it...

Comment: I mean it is unusual to add children (Elements) to a component outside of the Flex Component LifeCycle.  Given your snippet; don't know when created() is called; but I assume it is not called from within createChildren().

Comment: created() is called when the view is created. What is the downside of using .dataPrvider.addItem(item); versus .dataProvider = items; ?

Comment: When is the view created?  You mean it is called as part of a constructor?  Or do you mean something else? Read about the Flex Component LifeCycle here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS460ee381960520ad-2811830c121e9107ecb-7fff.html .  I would expect that calling dataProvider.addItem() will cause the list to redraw with each added item.  Whereas dataProvider = items will cause the list to redraw itself only once no matter how many items are added (or removed or changed).  addItem is fine if you're just updating a single item; but I wouldn't not use that for the initial dataprovider set

Comment: View is created by TabbedViewNavigatorApplication. I only have 1 tab so it is called automatically (firstView="views.LatestView"). created() is then called on creation of the view.

Comment: Still can't wrap my head arond it. Could the scroller issue be related to the fact that I am creating the list component within the View? This seems to be the biggest change I've made before the issue. If so then is my only option to wait for the HTTPService in the Main.mxml and then create the ViewNavigators? This would be very troublesome for me because I would have to detect the click of the #tabBar button before calling HTTService...

Comment: OK, I seem to have pinpointed the cause of the issue. It seems that The s:View that contains the s:List has the height property of 10 000. Is this normal behavior? Entering a pixel value or percentage lower than 100 renders the scroll bar visible and functional.

Comment: I would not expect that to be normal behavior; no.  But if you don't set a specific height then the height is measured.  It uses the measure() method of the component [or if a view is a Spark Component, the view's Skin].  If you want to investigate further; you may want to put a breakpoint in the measure method to see what is going on.

Comment: It looks like I just needed to set the height to 100% where I was defining s:ViewNavigator component, it all works now. Feel free to add an answer since you did guide me to the solution, Thanks.